# Read-Only attribute using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Verifying a Read-only attribute using Selenium.

`.getAttribute("readonly")` returns "true" if it is Read-only object and returns "null" if it is not a Read-only object

How to handle this? Is there any try catch required here?

```
String State = driver.findElement(By.id("Organisationname")).getAttribute("readonly");
```

This returns 'true' if textbox is Readonly and 'null' if it is not Readonly
  I am trying below if else condition.But while moving to else statement InvocationTargetException is coming up

Is it becuase of return types true and null

```
                             if(State .contains("true")){
                                 System.out.println("readonly");
                             }else{
                                 System.out.println("not readonly");
                             }
```

Comment: What is that you want to accomplish? Have a read through [ask].

Comment: String State = driver.findElement(By.id("Organisationname")).getAttribute("readonly");   This returns 'true' if textbox is Readonly and 'null' if it is not Readonly
                              
                              if(State .contains("true")){
                               System.out.println("readonly");
                              }else{
                               System.out.println("not readonly");
                              }

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Selenium, this is purely a Java problem!

You need to first test for the `null` condition.

```
    String state = driver.findElement(By.id("Organisationname")).getAttribute("readonly");
    if (state == null) {
        System.out.println("not");
    } else if (state.contains("true")) {
        System.out.println("good");
    } else {
        System.out.println("unknown");
    }
```